# How to prepare a successful application for Irish visa as a family member of an EU citizen?

Tags: ireland, family, eu-citizens, freedom-of-movement

My husband is a British citizen and currently living in the UK. I am a Pakistani national and currently living in Pakistan. I want to apply for a visa of family member of an EU citizen. I also have refusal letter for short term study visa for UK in 2017. I have read the required documents needed for the visa. According to directives, there is no need to provide accommodation and travel plan and bank statements. But I have read some refusals for a family member of an EU citizen on the basis that they did not provide accommodation and travel plans and did not show their ties with Ireland.

I will travel to Ireland with my husband. The documents which I need to provide are:

1. my passport
2. Copy of my husband's passport
3. marriage certificate
4. Invitation letter from my husband stating that he is a British citizen and will travel with me and has right of free movement.
5. letter from the applicant (me)
6. My refusal letter for UK short term study visa

What else do I need to attach with the application?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to include the refusal letter for the UK student visa, and your husband's letter does not need to state that he has freedom of movement, since they should know that.  But including these things won't hurt your application, either.

If you are refused because you haven't shown your accommodation or travel plans, or documented ties to Ireland or any other country, that refusal will be improper and you will be able to appeal it.

Comment: thank you for your response. but there is a question in application for visa refusals of any other country and in document list, it is mentioned to attach refusal letter as well.

Comment: @FatimaKhan they shouldn't be asking that of applicants for free-movement visas.